# How to solve OBS is not recording all instance of a window

Tags: windows, screen-recorder, obs-studio

For some reason, I am using an OBS recorder for recording a Webex recording in its `nbr recording player`. But the problem is it is not recording the chat and other windows which are instances of the recording player, it is just recording the video. Also, it is not showing any option for selecting a chat window in OBS window capture option.

| `Actual screen` | `Screen which are getting recorded` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I am using OBS for the first time and I don't have any idea how to fix this

Comment: You can record the entire monitor instead of just the application window.

Comment: I have some privacy issue, so I can't

Comment: I've had a similar problem with OBS (where certain elements in the same window are ignored or delayed). For me, it was hardware drivers -- trying to record the same thing on a different computer worked perfectly (same software, OS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they may possibly be different windows or frames.  So perhaps you can add each as a source.

Failing that you can add the source "colour" and then put that over the parts that are private which would then leave odd squares/rectangles all over the place.

A better solution might be to resize the full window capture so that it only shows the part of your screen that you want to show.  You may encounter a problem with resolution if you grow it a lot potentially.  To do this just find the bottom/top right/left corner of the screen and click and drag.